# How to use mock objects in this junit

Tags: java

How can i use mock objects in this junit testing??
I need to implement mock objects in junit.
Need help in regarding this code.

```
public class TicketTest {
public static List<Ticket> tickList = new ArrayList<Ticket>();


@Before
public void setup() throws Exception {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

}

@Test
public void objectValueSetting() throws Exception {
    Ticket ticket = new Ticket();
    ticket.setDescription("helllo");
    ticket.setEmail("me@helloooo.com");
    tickList.add(ticket);

}

@Test
public void valueGetting() throws Exception {

    Ticket ticket = tickList.get(0);
    Assert.assertNotNull(ticket);
    Assert.assertNotNull(ticket.getDescription());
    Assert.assertNotNull(ticket.getEmail());

}
```

}

Comment: Why do you need to mock anything? What are you trying to test? Your question is really unclear at the moment. Please read http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you want to mock ? (Not able to comment. So writing it here)
If you want to mock Ticket Class then the code will look like

` 
     @Test
         public void valueGetting() throws Exception {

```
   Ticket mock= Mockito.mock(Ticket.class);
    when(mock.getDescription()).thenReturn("hello");
    when(mock.getEmail()).thenReturn("me@helloooo.com");
    Assert.assertNotNull(mock);
    Assert.assertNotNull(mock.getDescription());
    Assert.assertNotNull(mock.getEmail());

}
```

`

PS : I am using mockito.

Comment: it is showing this error The method when(String) is undefined for the type TicketTest @AarYem

Comment: Pls check if you have done static import ie `import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;` so that you can use when method